# How choose smoothing function for Generative Additive Models? (GAMs)

Tags: r, machine-learning, model-selection, generalized-additive-model, smoothing

I would like to know which strategies are used in practice to choose the correct smoothing function for each features in the GAMs, both for classification and regression tasks.  I thought of plotting a 2D graph and checking the trend of the distribution of the values ​​of a features with respect to the classes / numerical outputs (for regression) and on the basis of this choose whether to use an appropriate smoothing function or linear function.

Comment: The "G" stands for "Generalized" (with the same meaning as in [GLM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_linear_model)). Anyway, I'd recommend using `mgcv:gam`, which uses penalized regression splines (and can therefore reduce the smoothers' "wiggliness" to a linear relationship or even remove them).

Comment: Sisi excuse me, typing error. Thank you very much for your reply. So what you told me would be equivalent if using a P-Splines. However, I wanted a display method that would allow me to check in advance whether a Features has a linear distribution or not with respect to the class. That's why I thought I was viewing a 2D chart with all the values ​​of a Feature

Comment: That works as long as you have exactly one feature.

Comment: No obviously this has to be repeated for each input features.  I do this reasoning because a Smoothing function is applied for each Fetures in the GAMs.  Therefore the final model will be given by the additivity of these smoothing functions

Comment: Yes, but you can't inspect these smoothing functions without fitting the model and changing one of them also impacts the other ones.

Comment: okok yeah, you're right thanks a lot.  But what I mean is to make these 2D visualizations, just to understand in advance if a Smoothing Function is needed for a particular Feature or not.  In order to apply the smoothing functions only to the features that produce non-linear effects on the dependent variable.  Is this correct reasoning?

Comment: You cannot plot marginal effects without fitting a model.

Comment: Okok is fine, this is because the various smoothing functions during training depend on each other.  So ultimately, you should regardless apply for example a penalized regression spline TO EVERY FEATURES, and then it will be its penalty term to determine the degree of smoothing for a given feature right?  While the degree to be initially associated with the smoothing function, how is it determined?  Through Cross-Validation by performing fine-tuning?